# Changing the values inside an object within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I am trying extract an array that is inside an object in an array and I want to edit the value of the objects within that extracted array. It seems like this should be simple but I cant figure out why my forEach isnt updating the objects. From what I understand forEach mutates the original array so why isnt this working?

My expected result would be:

```
      [
          {
            "label": "400 mg",
            "value": "400 mg",
          },
          {
             "label": "600 mg",
             "value": "600 mg",
          },
          {
             "label": "800 mg",
             "value": "800 mg",
          }
      ]
```

```js
const array1 = [
        {
            "Name": "IBU (oral - tablet)",
            "Strength": [
                {
                    "Strength": "400 mg",
                    "NDC": "55111068201"
                },
                {
                    "Strength": "600 mg",
                    "NDC": "55111068301"
                },
                {
                    "Strength": "800 mg",
                    "NDC": "55111068401"
                }
            ]
        },          
    ];

let newA = array1.map((item) => item.Strength).flatMap((item) => item)

newA.forEach((str) => ({label: str.Strength ,value: str.Strength}))


console.log(newA)
```

Comment: The [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method executes a provided function once for each array element without having any `return`. In your `forEach` you create a new `object` which does not get used nor returned. `newA.forEach((item) => {item.label = item.Strength})` would change the initial object.

Comment: You should not try to use .forEach method on arrays, you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map - with this you can achieve your desired result.

Comment: @NicolaeMaties I see what you mean I was trying not to use .map method over an over. I could just map over the newArr again but I was thinking there might be a better way that doesnt involve creating a new copy of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for this, using .map not .forEach.

```js
const result = [
        {
            "Name": "IBU (oral - tablet)",
            "Strength": [
                {
                    "Strength": "400 mg",
                    "NDC": "55111068201"
                },
                {
                    "Strength": "600 mg",
                    "NDC": "55111068301"
                },
                {
                    "Strength": "800 mg",
                    "NDC": "55111068401"
                }
            ]
        }    
][0].Strength.map(el => ({ label: el.Strength, value: el.Strength }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array1 = [
        {
            "Name": "IBU (oral - tablet)",
            "Strength": [
                {
                    "Strength": "400 mg",
                    "NDC": "55111068201"
                },
                {
                    "Strength": "600 mg",
                    "NDC": "55111068301"
                },
                {
                    "Strength": "800 mg",
                    "NDC": "55111068401"
                }
            ]
        },          
    ];

let newA = array1.map((item) => item.Strength).flatMap((item) => item)

newA.map((str) => {
  str.label= str.Strength ;
  str.value = str.Strength;
  delete str.Strength;
  delete str.NDC
})
console.log(newA)
```

Comment: This returns the same value as my attempt. I see what youre trying to do. I think you forgot to assign the second map a var name.